# Как реализовать оповещение при приближении к какому-либо объекту

Tags: android, google-maps-api, gps

Есть у меня, допустим, несколько объектов с координатами, и при подходе к одному их них я должен получать оповещение. В принципе, если объектов не много то можно сделать сервис который будет регулярно просчитывать расстояние до объектов. Но если объектов больше двух тысяч, это же сильно ударит по производительности или нет? Или может у гугла на этот счет есть какое-либо апи? Или есть какой-то особый подход к этому вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [LocationManager.addProximityAlert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html):

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context, 
    requestCode, //см. ниже
    intent, // интент с нужными вам extras
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

locationManager.addProximityAlert(
    latitude, // широта
    longitude, // долгота
    POINT_RADIUS, // радиус оповещения
    PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // таймаут оповещения, -1 для "навсегда"
    proximityIntent 
);
```

Для каждой новой локации задаете свой `requestCode`, ну и дальше регистрируете ресивер, ловите оповещения.

[Тут](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html) полный пример добавления одного alert'а.